# How to split the tick with a date in two rows?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bar chart with the X axis, which have ticks that include the month and year. The month and year are in the single row now.

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(x)
                  .orient("bottom")
                  .tickFormat(RU.timeFormat("%b %Y"));
```

I need to leave the month in the first line and move the year in the second one.

```
svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
   .call(xAxis);
```

Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/uaygrmLo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this nice "wrap text function", written by Bostock: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321

Using this function, I just modified your axis:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll(".tick text")
    .call(wrap, 40);
```

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/aLc8t6yq/

PS: I used 40 here as a magic number, change it according to your needs.

Comment: What does mean "40" in `.call(wrap, 40);`? I can't figure it out, would you explain me this?

Comment: The maximum width (in px) used to wrap the text.